# Cut array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to cut array in php. My array is listed below :

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 6/1/2014
    [1] => 6/2/2014
    [2] => 6/3/2014
    [3] => 6/4/2014
    [4] => 6/5/2014
    [5] => 6/6/2014
    [6] => 6/7/2014
    [7] => 6/8/2014
    [8] => 6/9/2014
    [9] => 6/10/2014
    [10] => 6/11/2014
    [11] => 6/12/2014
    [12] => 6/13/2014
    [13] => 6/14/2014
    [14] => 6/15/2014
    [15] => 6/16/2014
    [16] => 6/17/2014
    [17] => 6/18/2014
    [18] => 6/19/2014
    [19] => 6/20/2014
    [20] => 6/21/2014
    [21] => 6/22/2014
    [22] => 6/23/2014
    [23] => 6/24/2014
    [24] => 6/25/2014
    [25] => 6/26/2014
    [26] => 6/27/2014
    [27] => 6/28/2014
    [28] => 6/29/2014
    [29] => 6/30/2014
    [30] => 7/1/2014
    [31] => 7/2/2014
    [32] => 7/3/2014
    [33] => 7/4/2014
    [34] => 7/5/2014
    [35] => 7/6/2014
    [36] => 7/7/2014
    [37] => 7/8/2014
    [38] => 7/9/2014
    [39] => 7/10/2014
    [40] => 7/11/2014
    [41] => 7/12/2014
    [42] => 7/13/2014
    [43] => 7/14/2014
    [44] => 7/15/2014
    [45] => 7/16/2014
    [46] => 7/17/2014
    [47] => 7/18/2014
    [48] => 7/19/2014
    [49] => 7/20/2014
    [50] => 7/21/2014
    [51] => 7/22/2014
    [52] => 7/23/2014
    [53] => 7/24/2014
    [54] => 7/25/2014
    [55] => 7/26/2014
    [56] => 7/27/2014
    [57] => 7/28/2014
    [58] => 7/29/2014
    [59] => 7/30/2014
    [60] => 7/31/2014
    [61] => 8/1/2014
)
```

In this array 0 to 29 elements if for 6th Month, 30th to 60th elements are for 7th Month etc..

Now i want this array in the below fashion

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 6/1/2014
    [1] => 6/2/2014
    [2] => 6/3/2014
    [3] => 6/4/2014
    [4] => 6/5/2014
    [5] => 6/6/2014
    [6] => 6/7/2014
    [7] => 6/8/2014
    [8] => 6/9/2014
    [9] => 6/10/2014
    [10] => 6/11/2014
    [11] => 6/12/2014
    [12] => 6/13/2014
    [13] => 6/14/2014
    [14] => 6/15/2014
    [15] => 6/16/2014
    [16] => 6/17/2014
    [17] => 6/18/2014
    [18] => 6/19/2014
    [19] => 6/20/2014
    [20] => 6/21/2014
    [21] => 6/22/2014
    [22] => 6/23/2014
    [23] => 6/24/2014
    [24] => 6/25/2014
    [25] => 6/26/2014
    [26] => 6/27/2014
    [27] => 6/28/2014
    [28] => 6/29/2014
    [29] => 6/30/2014
)


Array
(
    [0] => 7/1/2014
    [1] => 7/2/2014
    [2] => 7/3/2014
    [3] => 7/4/2014
    [4] => 7/5/2014
    [5] => 7/6/2014
    [6] => 7/7/2014
    [7] => 7/8/2014
    [8] => 7/9/2014
    [9] => 7/10/2014
    [10] => 7/11/2014
    [11] => 7/12/2014
    [12] => 7/13/2014
    [13] => 7/14/2014
    [14] => 7/15/2014
    [15] => 7/16/2014
    [16] => 7/17/2014
    [17] => 7/18/2014
    [18] => 7/19/2014
    [19] => 7/20/2014
    [20] => 7/21/2014
    [21] => 7/22/2014
    [22] => 7/23/2014
    [23] => 7/24/2014
    [24] => 7/25/2014
    [25] => 7/26/2014
    [26] => 7/27/2014
    [27] => 7/28/2014
    [28] => 7/29/2014
    [29] => 7/30/2014
    [30] => 7/31/2014
)

Array
(
    [0] => 8/1/2014
)
```

This calculation should be in a way that if i chose other months then it also do the same process of cutting array for different months.

you can also separate array by month & and put them in main array

Comment: Try `$result = array_chunk($your_array,30);print_r($result);`

Comment: You can use a combination of [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

Comment: @Uchiha i want this thing to be done dynamically, not by specific indexing. Only want to chunck array of different months. In my result it is not fixed that first 30 elements will be of specific months.

Comment: at least try man. coz I hate to write code from scratch. :S

Comment: What about a `foreach` loop and checking the first two chars, trimming the `/ ` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrres =array();
foreach($arr as $value)
{
  $arrres[str_replace('/','',substr($value,0,2))][] = $value ;
}
print_r($arrres);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd explode the value of every index in your array and set it as an index to the new array.

```
$days = [];
foreach($your_array as $day) {
 $days[ explode("/", $day)[0] ][] = $day;

}

var_dump( $days );
```

Comment: NetBeans learnt me to use $array = [ ]; so it's kinda bad habit of mine now.

Comment: Quite the opposite - PHP's shorthand array format has been a feature since 5.4, and since this the least supported version, I would say it's not a bad habit at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:, it will also generate arrays with same num of days in months (28,30,31)

```
//generate dates for test
$dates = [];
for($i = 0 ; $i < 90 ; $i++){
    $dates[] = Date("d/m/Y",time()-($i*24*3600));
}

//make results, also validates that it's same month and year
$result = [];
foreach($dates as $date){
    $dStr = Date("m-y",strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date)));
    if(!isset($result[$dStr])) $result[$dStr] = [];

    $result[$dStr][] = $date;
}

var_dump($result);
```